# How is work done by Tension zero in this case?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

[image]

How is the work done by tension zero in this case. There is no horizontal force acting so the centre of mass won't displace in the horizontal direction as it will be in vertical.

But the work done by tension in $m$ should be $T2l/3 \cos\theta$ and $2m$ should have been $T✓l^2 + 2l^2/3 \cos\theta$. How is it zero?

Answer (score 0):

The work done by a force $F$ is

$$W=Fd$$

Where $d$ is the distance in line with the force, over which something is displaced.

In your figure, as the weight falls there is never a point when the rope pulls the weight *along the direction of the rope*.  Therefore no work is done.

The same is true for a weight being spun horizontally around in a circle attached to a rope. The tension is always at 90 degrees to the displacement, so no work is ever done.  In this latter case, this is confirmed by the fact that the kinetic energy remains constant.

Comment: And what about the small bead on the fixed string?I failed to represent it in fig but in the question the small bead is also moving .

Comment: As yourself, does it move a distance $d$ along the line of action of a force $F$?

Comment: No.But it does move along horizontal in which Tcostheta is involved .

Comment: It's difficult to tell from the figure exactly what is happening.  Perhaps you can add a sentence or two to describe it. If you can draw a free body diagram of both masses, that will help you as well

Comment: Ok i added some pics with free body.So tension doesn't do work in 2m mass body .But in m tension is clearly doing work .My tutor used conservation of mechanical energy but I can't grasp the concept when tension is non conservative force and it is clearly displacing the m mass body.But my tutor said net work done by tension would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the massless and inextensible string has two equal magnitude forces and opposite direction forces acting on it and we call those forces *tension*, $T$.

So the work done on each element of the string is $T\,d + (-T)\,d = 0$ where $d$ is the displacement of the element along the line of action of the tension forces.

Note also that as the string is massless no work can be done on it! - If you are not sure about this think about the work-energy theorem.

Comment: In my fig the small mass m has been displaced by some distance 'd ' by tension.I am just confused as a object has been displaced by some distance then shouldn't there work be done by tension on that object?

Comment: Look at the system as a whole.  The system loses gravitational potential energy (mass $2m$) falls and gains an equal amount of kinetic energy and the two ends of the string do not move relative to one another.

Comment: Ohh ok so rather than dividing the system should i look for whole system motion and like that work done by tension would be zero when small m bead reaches the 2m mass(original place).And it would perform motion like simple harmonic motion?

Comment: Maybe my figure isn't clear but the small mass m ( the point where the string is connnected in upper side ) is also moving with velocity .I am confused on the  work done on it by tension.